How to create this custom BottomSheet with a draghandler design?
I am currently trying to figure out how to create a custom bottomsheet with a draghandler (see image). I have searched a bit on the internet and watched a few videos and it is to my understanding that I have to somehow use Canvas and draw this shape onto the bottomsheet but can not figure out how to do this.
I have created a bottomsheet but how can I achieve this design? Appreciate an explanation as to how to think as well!
Image of design:

BottomSheet:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun ChatLayout() {
    // State for showing/hiding the bottom sheet
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        skipPartiallyExpanded = true, // Skip the half-expanded state
        confirmValueChange = { false } // Prevent state changes like hiding
    )
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    // Automatically show the bottom sheet when the Composable is displayed
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        coroutineScope.launch { sheetState.show() }
    }

    // UI Content
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        // Bottom Sheet
        if (sheetState.isVisible) {
            ModalBottomSheet(
                onDismissRequest = {
                    // Do nothing here
                },
                sheetState = sheetState,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                // Ensure that the bottom sheet expands from bottom to top
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .fillMaxHeight(0.8f) // 80% height of the screen
                        .padding(16.dp)
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Bottom Sheet Title",
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineMedium
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
                    Text(
                        text = "This bottom sheet expands from bottom to top. Adjust content as needed.",
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium
                    )

                }
            }
        }
    }
}


you have dragHandle and you give custom implementation. You might need to check about bezeir cruves and provide a custom curved shape

ah I see, so I can implement a bezier curve at the top of the bottomsheet and place the draghandler in the center of it. After that, customize the draghandler to my liking. Awesome, thanks for the suggestion and direction! @Raghunandan
